# angular ngHide on a button leaves space where it was

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In the footer of this html file, I have 3 buttons.

The first image shows how the 3 buttons are arranged.
The second image shows is when the footer middle button is commented out.
The third image is when ng-hide="true" on the middle button.

How can I have no space between the No and YES buttons when the middle is ngHide(n)? Thanks

[image]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 1%;
}

header > button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label.pageTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

main, .mainMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5em;
}

main {
    z-index: -2;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

footer > button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;

}
section {
    text-align: center;
}
input {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    width: 90%;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: white;
}

.horizontal-style {
    display: table;
    width: 100%
}
.horizontal-style li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
}
.horizontal-style button {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background: #dfdfdf;
}

footer button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.mainMenu {
    padding-left: 1em;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    width: 70%;
    border-radius: 0 6px 10px 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 0.25em;
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 0em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="appModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <base href="http://localhost:63342/students/">

    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>-->
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <script src="services/routing.js"></script>
    <script src="services/menuToggle.js"></script>

    <script src="controllers/menuToggleCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/mainMenuCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/page1Ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/page2Ctrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header ng-controller="MenuToggleCtrl">
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" ng-model="clicked" ng-click="menuToggle()">&#9776;</button>
    <label id="pageTitle" class="pageTitle">Select item from list</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<section class="mainMenu" ng-controller="MainMenuCtrl" ng-if="!clicked">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <a href="#/{{item.name}}">
                <image ng-src="images/{{item.image}}.png"></image>
                {{item.name}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>

<main ng-view></main>

<footer ng-controller="MenuToggleCtrl" ng-if="clicked">
    <ul class="horizontal-style">
        <li><button type="button">NO</button></li>
        <li><button type="button">EXTRA</button></li>
        <!--<li><button type="button">EXTRA</button></li>-->
        <!--<li><button type="button" ng-hide="true">EXTRA</button></li>-->
        <li><button type="button">YES</button></li>
    </ul>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the entire li by applying ng-hide to li element.

```
<li ng-hide={{expression}}><button type="button">EXTRA</button></li>
```

NOTE: You can also use `ng-if` instead of `ng-hide` which will completely remove the `<li>` from DOM and can prove performant with large content inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code this is fine. you are hiding the below button

```
<button type="button">EXTRA</button>
```

You need to hide full below li

```
 <li><button type="button">EXTRA</button></li>
```

This works fine.

Comment: Let me know if more help needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the button alone, still the li is visible and some of the styles added to li creates some spacing between two buttons.

Hide the entire li by applying ng-hide to li element.

```
<li ng-hide="true"><button type="button">EXTRA</button></li>
```